# Angular2 innerHtml constantly updating

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml

I think this is more of a style question than anything but I want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

I have an endpoint that I am calling which is annoyingly returning a SVG image instead of a full jpeg or png and I need to display that on the page. I created a service that calls out and grabs the SVG. That service gets called from a method in the component called getImage(id).

In my HTML I have something like:

```
<div [innerHtml]="getImage(id)></div>
```

One thing I noticed is that I can't really inspect the SVG in chrome because it's constantly updating. I am wondering if this is a problem and if so how to fix it? It looks like it's just constantly calling the update method but nothing has changed on the page (as far as I can tell) so the change detection shouldn't be triggered?

Comment: Get the image in `ngOnInit()` and set it to a variable. Use that variable in `[innerHtml]`.

Comment: Question - Why is the svg not being attached to the src attribute of an img element?

Answer (score 3):

Example for my comment:

```
import { ..., OnInit, ... } from '@angular/core'

@Component({ ... })
export class ...Component implements OnInit {
   private image: string;

   constructor(...) { ... }

   public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getImage(1); //Get id from somewhere
   }

   private getImage(id): void {
      ...
      this.image = ...;
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<div [innerHtml]="image"></div>
```